# Excel - Find highest MULTI-cell Total

Tags: excel, database, syntax

[image: 2003-2004 is the largest two-year/cell stretch----how to code this?]

Hello!

Is it possible to have Excel find the largest two, three or four cell total within its data?  For example, dates are entered as 2000, 2001, 2002, etc in column A and in column B, there's another figure, HRs.  I have my document sorted by dates (columnA) and now want to see the most HRs hit over two seasons.  This seems very useful and utilized in data but still under-realized.

-Most touchdowns over a two-season stretch. (most touchdowns over a THREE season stretch etc.)
-Highest-grossing 3-month stretch.
-Rainiest two days ever
-Most speeding tickets issued in two days.
-Largest two-day Jeopardy winnings.
-ETC

**Can I search through an excel document and see the largest 2-day rainfall as described?**  Something similar to "Find All" in excel but for consecutive cells, though, that doesn't find largest I suppose.  It'd be cool, if you could drag a range, say 3 cells tall, within a larger range, and Excel could find that largest totals in that larger range.

I doubt this is possible---but surely there is a way data scientists or just newspapers can organize data to find the largest total over a certain stretch?  (most HR over a 5-season stretch)  How could I do this?  Maybe this requires a program for SQL or something?  Thank you.

https://www.exceltip.com/summing/sum-the-largest-two-numbers-in-range-in-microsoft-excel.html
This seems close, but just finds the two largest figures----not the two largest *consecutive* figures, which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Formula or macro solution?

Comment: Yes you could certainly do it by an offset/subtotal combination or possibly offset ranges =max(a2:a12+a3:a13) for small numbers of adjacent cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using offset ranges:

```
=MAX(B2:B12+B3:B13)
```

or subtotal/offset combo:

```
=MAX(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(B1,ROW(B1:B11),0,2,1)))
```

(the first one gets cumbersome when extended to 3,4,5... adjacent cells)

must be entered as array formulas using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

**EDIT**

If you wanted to find the first, second etc. largest pair you could use Large instead of Max:

```
=LARGE(B$2:B$12+B$3:B$13,ROW()-1)
```

or

```
=LARGE(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(B$1,ROW(B$1:B$11),0,2,1)),ROW()-1)
```

and then to find the year, use Index/match:

```
=INDEX(A$2:A$12,MATCH(F2,SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(B$1,ROW(B$1:B$11),0,2,1)),0))
```

The only drawback of this is that if there were two pairs giving the same maximum of 84 say, the index/match would still match the year of the first one. This can be addressed but maybe that is enough for now.

Comment: This is fabulous Tom Sharpe!  Thank you.  What really could complete a tool like this is being able to see WHAT or WHO ranked 1st in a large set of data for the highest consecutive total.

I'm working with your Method 2 for the ability to do 2 straight, 3 straight etc. but I think want to use more of a "Large" function to be able to rank this?  Who's 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc.  In the early goings, Excel says I've added an argument with "Large" Perhaps not configured with your great solution.

1.  Can Excel say what cells provided the Max or product?
2.  How to rank or find the 2nd, 3rd etc?

Comment: Thanks! Yes it would be useful to find out which was the largest (or second largest) etc - will have a look at it today.

Comment: Hi Mr. Sharpe, here is a solution to the "ties" being represented by the first instance:  

https://www.accountingweb.com/technology/excel/utilizing-excels-countif-function-to-break-ties

It doesn't involve changing your formula at all, just changing ties, 84 in your example to UNIQUE VALUES so 84.00000 and 84.00001 and so on for every instance of that number.  I'm trying to use this for alot of data and it seems to scale great, just a matter of adding a column to build that extra number. but outside of updating when new data arrives, should work great.  Thank you so much--favorite website